# Suppress print newline in python 3 str.format

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, format, newline

I am using Python 3 and am trying to use my print statements with the str.format.

e.g:

```
print ('{0:3d} {1:6d} {2:10s} '.format (count1,count2,string1))
```

When I try to use the `end=''` to suppress the subsequent newline, this is ignored. A newline always happens.

How do I suppress the subsequent newline?

Source:

```
int1= 1
int2 = 999
string1 = 'qwerty'
print ( '{0:3d} {1:6d} {2:10s} '.format (int1,int2,string1))
print ('newline')
print ( '{0:3d} {1:6d} {2:10s} '.format (int1,int2,string1,end=''))
print ('newline')
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
```

> 1    999 qwerty
>   newline
>
> 1    999 qwerty
>   newline

Comment: Can you show your code that you used when you attempted to use the `end` argument?

Comment: @skrrgwasme - the code is added above. The output somehow got split, but it is the same both for both print statements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you have the `end=''` argument being passed to the `format` function, not to the `print` function.

Change this line:

```
print ( '{0:3d} {1:6d} {2:10s} '.format (int1,int2,string1,end=''))
```

To this:

```
print ( '{0:3d} {1:6d} {2:10s} '.format (int1,int2,string1), end='')
```

By the way, you should also give [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) a read. It defines standards for Python coding styles, that you really should try to follow, unless you're working with a group of people that have agreed on some other style standards. In particular, your spacing is a bit weird around function calls - you shouldn't have spaces between function names and the argument parentheses, or between the parentheses and the first argument. I wrote my suggested solution to your problem in a way that maintains your current style, but it really should look more like this:

```
print('{0:3d} {1:6d} {2:10s} '.format(int1, int2, string1), end='')
```